# Should "SCRUM" be written in all caps?

Tags: scrum

I see a lot of people put "SCRUM" in all caps.  I go with the title case "Scrum" myself though.  Which is correct?  As far as I know, it's not an acronym, so I am guessing "Scrum" is correct.

Comment: No.  See the document written by the creators of the framework: [The Scrum Guide](https://scrumguides.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, "Scrum" is correct. See http://www.scrumalliance.org/